# How to control the flow in nested if statement?

Tags: python

I'm programming Clarke and Wright's savings algorithm to design vehicle routes from a depot to a set of customers. Right now, the code gets stuck in the final nested if statement if none of the conditions is met. What I want is that if none of the conditions is met, the code should break out of the second for loop. And then, go back to the first for loop to find a customer pair for starting a new route.

I've tried some things with 'break' and 'continue' but can not get it working.

```py
while(not(allCustomersConsidered(customerServed))):
#choosing the maximum savings customers who are unserved
    for c in cust_pairs:
        if (isServed(c[0]) == False and isServed(c[1]) == False) and check1(c[0]) and check2(c[0], c[1]):

            hasBeenServed(c[0])
            hasBeenServed(c[1])
            idx += 1
            routes[idx] = ([c[0],c[1]]) 
            print("initial", c[0], c[1])
            break

    #finding a cust that is either at the start or end of previous route
    for c in cust_pairs:
        res = inPrevious(c[0], routes[idx])
        if res == 0 and capacityValid(routes[idx], c[1]) and (isServed(c[1]) == false) and check(routes[idx], c[1]):

            hasBeenServed(c[1])
            routes[idx].append(c[1])
            print("append", c[1])

         elif res == 1 and capacityValid(routes[idx], c[1]) and (isServed(c[1]) == False) and checkS(c[1]) and all(test(routes[idx], r, c[1]) for r in routes[idx]):

            hasBeenServed(c[1])
            routes[idx].insert(0,c[1])
            print("insert", c[1])

        elif res == -1:
            res = inPrevious(c[1], routes[idx])
            if res == 0 and capacityValid(routes[idx], c[0]) and (isServed(c[0]) == False) and check(routes[idx], c[0]):

                hasBeenServed(c[0])
                routes[idx].append(c[0]) 
                print("append2", c[0])

            elif res == 1 and capacityValid(routes[idx], c[0]) and (isServed(c[0]) == False) and checkS(c[0]) and all(test(routes[idx], r, c[0]) for r in routes[idx]):

                hasBeenServed(c[0])
                routes[idx].insert(0,c[0])
                print("insert2", c[0])
```

Comment: for sure, you should add an `else` condition to the `if` statements, to account for errors. If none of the above, then either throw exception, if applicable, or, in your case, go back to first cycle. The 2nd `for` loop will end by itself, going back to evaluating the `while` condition and executing the 1st `for` loop. I believe that maybe your code gets stuck because you run out of couples that can meet the `while` criteria.

Comment: indeed, sth about a final `else` should be the way to go. However, please edit your code such that it is _really_ equal to what you use, as currently the first line isn't marked as code at all so this creates doubts if all indentations are set correctly; or even better: cut it all down to a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, I know that there should be an else statement below all the if statements but I don't know what to write there. I think that the code gets stuck when it has found an initial customer pair to start a route with in the 1st for loop and after that, if there is no unserved customer pair meeting the conditions. Therefore, I'm looking for some part of code that gives a trigger to start a new route using the 1st for loop.

Comment: @Marc we can't execute your code snippet, nor really reason about it. Please reduce it to a proper  [MCVE]

Comment: @Marc, put some print in the `While` and `For` loops. That'll give you a sense of what is going on. Then, by all means, provide the MRE (that means also an example of `cust_pairs` and all...).

Comment: My code is based on this code: https://github.com/shlok57/VehicleRoutingProblem/blob/master/Savings/cvrpImprovedImpl.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems in your implementation. The algorithm states that neither node in the pair should be internal to its route, i.e. they should both be still connected to the depot. Yet you do not check that in the beginning of the second loop. The structure of the algorithm is not evident in your code. Here is some pseudocode to get you started:

```
savings = generate_savings(cust_pairs)

for pair in ordered(savings):
    res1 = isMidpoint(pair.cust1)
    res2 = isMidpoint(pair.cust2)
    if res1 or res2:
        continue
    elif satisfies_conditions(pair):
        merge_routes(routes(pair))
```

There is only one for loop, and it goes through the savings only once as they do not change and are always positive. No `while` is needed, and no breaking either.

Comment: I don't exactly get what you mean, but I check with the following method if one of the nodes in the customer pair already exists in the existing route: `def inPrevious(new,existing):
    start = existing[0]
    end = existing[len(existing)-1]
    if new == start:
        return 1
    elif new == end:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1`

Comment: Yes, I see you use `inPrevious` for that. But you only check the "last created route", `routes[idx]`, not all of them, and you can create branching routes this way.

Comment: I've started implementing the algorithm myself and edited the answer to reflect what I've found so far is needed. Turns out the control flow structure is quite simpler.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by with the `isMidpoint`. My intention is to look for a customer pair with the highest savings and iteratively add other customer pairs with high savings to the route if capacity and time window constraints are feasible. Afterwards, the depot will be added as starting point for the route, since the drivers don't have to return to the depot. Right now, the problem is that at some point, there are no customer pairs left with overlapping nodes in the current route. I want to prevent the code from getting stuck and just start a new route in case this happens.